# Blazor Server App - Modular Front-Ends (Micro-frontends)

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, micro-frontend

We are looking for a way to get Blazor Server loading other Blazor Server projects.
Our goal is to have a micro-frontend approach, where each micro-app is also a self-deployable app in itself and is also running from a base or shell application.

Has anyone achieved this?

Thanks

Comment: Please see if this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451989/multiple-blazor-projects-in-the-same-web-application/73365906#73365906

Comment: @cpt.oneeye Our solution finally was virtual directories on IIS and razor component libraries.